# How to run python programs having command line arguments in jenkins job

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python project having programs accepts command line arguments. I wanted to do integration testing. How can I run these program as Jenkins job ?

Comment: see https://serverfault.com/questions/760813/jenkins-python-script-with-arguments

Comment: I have multiple files to run as a test.